# QVariantMap dosen't work in QML with Clang Compiler - Segmentation fault

Tags: qt, qml, clang++, qvariant

I have a problem with passing `Q_PROPERTY` as `QVariantMap` to QML - Segmentation fault.
I created simple app to show the problem.
When I'm using compiler MinGW 11.2 everything is fine, but the problem is under Clang 15.0.4.

I have installed Clang by msys2 `mingw-w64-x86_64-clang` and `mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-toolchain`. Installing `mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-qt6` also didn't help.

Kit:
[image]

Compiler:
[image]

Error:
[image]

Code:

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "TestClass.h"
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

  TestClass t;
  engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("testClass", &t);

  const QUrl url(u"qrc:/QuickUI/qml/main.qml"_qs);
  QObject::connect(
      &engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated, &app,
      [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
          QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
      },
      Qt::QueuedConnection);
  engine.load(url);

  return app.exec();
}
```

TestClass.cpp

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <QObject>
#include <QVariantMap>

#include <QDebug>

class TestClass : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(QVariantMap testMap MEMBER testMap NOTIFY testMapChanged)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString testStr MEMBER testStr NOTIFY testMapChanged)

public:
  TestClass() : QObject() {}

  QVariantMap testMap;
  QString testStr = "test";

  Q_INVOKABLE void start() {
    qDebug() << "Kliknalem";
    testMap.insert("t1", "Mam 1");
    testMap.insert("t2", "Mam 2");

    emit testMapChanged();
  }

signals:
  void testMapChanged();
};
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "#FFFFFF"
    }

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.margins: 20
        spacing: 20

        Button {
            Layout.preferredHeight: 30
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            text: "Klik"

            onClicked: {
                testClass.start();
            }
        }

        Text {
            text: testClass.testStr
        }

        Text {
            text: testClass.testMap.t1
        }

        Text {
            text: testClass.testMap.t2
        }
    }
}
```

Stack:

```
1  QV4::ExecutionEngine::newIdentifier                                                                                                                                  

2  variantMapToJS                                                                                                                                                        

3  QV4::ExecutionEngine::fromData                                                                                                                                        

4  QV4::ExecutionEngine::fromVariant                                                                                                                                    

5  loadProperty                                                                                                                                                          

6  QV4::Moth::VME::interpret                                                                                                                                             

7  QV4::Moth::VME::exec                                                                                                                                                 

8  QV4::Function::call                                                                                                                                                  

9  QQmlJavaScriptExpression::evaluate                                                                                                                                    

10 QQmlBinding::evaluate                                                                                                                                                

11 QQmlNonbindingBinding::doUpdate                                                                                                                                       

12 QQmlBinding::update                                                                                                                                                  

13 QQmlNotifier::emitNotify                                                                                                                                             

14 doActivate<false>                                                                                                                                                     

15 TestClass::start()                                                                                                                                                   

16 TestClass::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void * *)                                                                                                             

17 QQmlObjectOrGadget::metacall                                                                                                                                          

18 CallMethod                                                                                                                                                           

19 CallPrecise                                                                                                                                                          

20 operator()                                                                                                                                                            

21 operator()<QV4::QObjectMethod::callInternal(const QV4::Value *, const QV4::Value *, int) const::<lambda()>>                                                          

22 QV4::QObjectMethod::callInternal                                                                                                                                     

23 QV4::FunctionObject::call                                                                                                                                             

24 QV4::Moth::VME::interpret                                                                                                                                            

25 QV4::Moth::VME::exec                                                                                                                                                 

26 QV4::Function::call                                                                                                                                                   

27 operator()                                                                                                                                                           

28 QV4::convertAndCall<QV4::Function::call(QObject *, void * *, const QMetaType *, int, QV4::ExecutionContext *)::<lambda(const QV4::Value *, const QV4::Value *, int)>>

29 QV4::Function::call                                                                                                                                                   

30 QQmlJavaScriptExpression::evaluate                                                                                                                                   

31 QQmlBoundSignalExpression::evaluate                                                                                                                                  

32 QQmlBoundSignal_callback                                                                                                                                              

33 QQmlNotifier::emitNotify                                                                                                                                             

34 doActivate<false>                                                                                                                                                    

35 QMetaObject::activate                                                                                                                                                 

36 QQuickAbstractButton::doubleClicked                                                                                                                                  

37 QQuickAbstractButtonPrivate::handleRelease                                                                                                                           

38 QQuickControl::mouseReleaseEvent                                                                                                                                      

39 QQuickItem::event                                                                                                                                                    

40 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2                                                                                                                                     

41 QCoreApplication::sendEvent                                                                                                                                          

42 QQuickDeliveryAgentPrivate::deliverMatchingPointsToItem                                                                                                              

43 QQuickDeliveryAgentPrivate::deliverUpdatedPoints                                                                                                                      

44 QQuickDeliveryAgentPrivate::deliverPointerEvent                                                                                                                      

45 QQuickDeliveryAgentPrivate::handleMouseEvent                                                                                                                         

46 QQuickDeliveryAgent::event                                                                                                                                            

47 QQuickWindow::event                                                                                                                                                  

48 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2                                                                                                                                    

49 QCoreApplication::sendSpontaneousEvent                                                                                                                                

50 QGuiApplicationPrivate::processMouseEvent                                                                                                                            

51 QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents                                                                                                                       

52 QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents                                                                                                                                  

53 QWindowsGuiEventDispatcher::processEvents                                                                                                                            

54 QEventLoop::processEvents                                                                                                                                            

55 QEventLoop::exec                                                                                                                                                      

56 QCoreApplication::exec                                                                                                                                               

57 qMain(int, char * *)                                                                                                                                                 

58 WinMain                                                                                                                                                               

59 main                                                                                                                                                                 

60 __tmainCRTStartup                                                                                                                                                    

61 WinMainCRTStartup
```

Comment: That's a pain. When did the crash occur? On startup? Or when you clicked on the Button? For map initialization, how about instead of using `insert` that you use the operator overload, i.e. `testMap["t1"] = QString("Mam 1");` ?

Comment: It happens when I click the button - so when I try to use that map.
I have also tried different map initialization (also your proposal) but without result.

Comment: Didi you try to debug that? According to the callstack that happens in the property getting, not in the `start()`. Btw, try to replace `testClass.testMap.t1` with `testClass.testMap["t1"]`

Comment: Yes, I have tried but still without result. Debug shows me exactly what I described in the post.

Comment: Do you have the same segfault when inserting only one item? (seems far fetched, but who knows)

Comment: Unfortunately the same error on `1   QV4::ExecutionEngine::newIdentifier   qv4engine.cpp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compile the Qt project with CLang, you must first compile the Qt itself with CLang.

To do this, you need a couple of things. First, read this source material (I will put tl;dr under, but it might not work): https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/windows-building.html (for Linux and others, refer to: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/build-sources.html).

Once you have all dependencies (like flex, bison, etc., installed), proceed to your source folder (either checked out from the repo or downloaded with your installation. Then open the environment of choice (msys2, local installs, cmd, or PowerShell). Enter the directory with source files and configure step, for example:

`./configure -release -opensource -confirm-license -prefix <OUTPUT_FOLDER_OF_YOUR_CHOICE>`

And wait for it to end. Then build with (by default) ninja:

`ninja` - you can use `-j` switch for more jobs. (`ninja -j6`)

And finish up with `ninja install`. With this, you should be able to run your CLang and qt by... coercion.

Note:

- QtWebEngine and QtPdf are not buildable with CLang

Commands:

```
./configure -release -opensource -confirm-license -prefix <OUTPUT_FOLDER_OF_YOUR_CHOICE>
ninja -j6
ninja install
```